# Как настроить Quartz.NET запускать job раз в 5 минут, начиная с текущего момента?

Tags: c#, quartz, jobscheduler

СобственноЮ вопрос сформулирован в заголовке: как сконфигурировать Quartz.NET немедленно запустить джобу, а затем запускать её каждые 5 минут? Пробовал вот такую конфигурацию, но не помогло: `"* /5 * * * ?"`

Comment: А для чего здесь вообще  Quartz.NET ? Почему бы не сделать это при помощи Timer с интервалом в 1000*5*60 ?

Comment: @Andrew потому что вы не сможете сделать интервал точно 5 минут, всегда будет накопительная погрешность, при чем всегда в плюс. Зависит от времени работы обработчика события `Tick`. То есть интервал будет 5 минут + время работы обработчика. Если точный интервал не требуется, то можно и с таймером.

Comment: Покажите код. который не работает.

Comment: А чем [официальная документация](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/) плоха?

Answer (score 0):

вы неправильно задали cron experssion

для запуска в каждые 5 минут используется `*/5 * * * * ?`
[image: гайд]